# SignalR Hub close connection from server side

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am working on a project where we use signalr to communicate with client. I got the case where client is connected to the server and he is using VPN.
Whenever he lost internet connection he obviously lost connection to hub, but from server side is looking like the connection is still active and OnDisconnectedAsync method is not triggered (half-open websocket?). When he reconnect he is connecting to hub with new connection with different connectionId and old connection is still hanging waiting to be closed.

My question is can i somehow close this connection from server side?

I implemented ping/pong functionality which are sending messages on websocket to client and waiting for response and i want to close this connection if i dont get any message back from client after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps overwritten some timeout methods?
Take a look at this article from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeoutkeepalive
It explains the lifetime of a connection and timeout functionality. Maybe this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: I did not change any timeout methods. All of them are set by default. I think it's because between client app and server i have proxy server and these timeout pings only goes to proxy and not from end to end (server to client app). What I did i passed whole HubCallerContext to service and when i do not get message back from client in period of time i just call method abort on that context which triggers method ondisconnectasync closing old connection.

Comment: Check if the KeepAlive is actually doing what it is supposed to do. I think you'd want to drop the conection if the keepalive fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the connections and disconnect serverside. Something along these lines.

```
public void Disconnect(string id)
{
    var all = GetConnectedClients();
    if (all.TryGetValue(id, out var connection))
    {
        connection.Abort();
    }
}

private System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, HubConnectionContext> GetConnectedClients()
{
    var lifetimeManagerPropInfo = this.Clients.All.GetType().GetField("_lifetimeManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var lifetimeManager = lifetimeManagerPropInfo.GetValue(this.Clients.All);
    var connectionsPropInfo = lifetimeManager.GetType().GetField("_connections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var connections = connectionsPropInfo.GetValue(lifetimeManager);
    var connectionsInnerPropInfo = connections.GetType().GetField("_connections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return connectionsInnerPropInfo.GetValue(connections) as System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, HubConnectionContext>;
}
```